# Dúvida em função no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma função no PostgreSQL e quero usá-la para checar se uma tabela já existe ou não em um banco de dados e, caso não exista, quero criar a tabela.

O problema está na declaração da função, que recebe um `varchar`, parâmetro que será utilizado para o `SELECT relname` e também para o `create` da tabela.

Segue a função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificarDb (tb varchar)RETURNS BOOLEAN as
$$
BEGIN
select relname from pg_class where relname = tb and relkind='r';
if not found then
        CREATE TABLE tb
        (
          id integer,
          nome varchar
        );
    return false;
end if;
if found then
return true;
end if; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
select verificarDb('tabela');
```

A verificação não está sendo feita pelo conteúdo do parâmetro `tb`, mas sim utilizando a string `tb`. No `create` também está usando a sigla `tb`, quero utilizar o nome da tabela passado por parâmetro, como faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui concluir a função, segue abaixo como ficou o esboço do código:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificarDb (tb varchar)RETURNS BOOLEAN as
    $$
    DECLARE result boolean;
    BEGIN
     execute format ('SELECT EXISTS (select 1 from pg_class where relname = 
    ''%s'' and relkind=''r'');', tb)
    INTO result;
    if result = FALSE then
      EXECUTE format ('CREATE TABLE "%s"
      (
        id integer,
        nome varchar
      );', tb);

        RETURN FALSE;
      ELSE
        RETURN TRUE;
      end if; 
     END;
     $$
     LANGUAGE plpgsql;
     --teste de função -> select verificarDb('tabela');
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificarDb(tb regclass, OUT result boolean) AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT EXISTS   (
                                        SELECT 1 
                                        FROM   pg_class c
                                        WHERE  relname = ''%s''
                                        AND    c.relkind = ''r''
                                    );', tb)
    INTO result;

    IF result = FALSE THEN
        CREATE TABLE tb
        (
          id    INTEGER,
          nome  VARCHAR
        );
    END IF;
END;
$$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Forma de utilização:

```
SELECT verificarDb('tabela');
```

Visto que venho mais de **SQL Server**, a sintaxe e a estrutura podem ter que sofrer ajustes, mas penso que não será difíci.